# Kerberos not working. - Can't find client principal in cache collection

Tags: kerberos

I was able to connect to my windows systems from linux box using domain credentials, when all of a sudden it stopped working. I have tried different accounts and different domains and getting the same error for every account --

> ""msg": "kerberos: authGSSClientInit() failed: (('Unspecified GSS
>   failure.  Minor code may provide more information', 851968), (\"Can't
>   find client principal user@domain in cache collection\",
>   -1765328243))","

The machine is running ubuntu, running Kerberos 5 version 1.12, and I have rebooted it as well. Klist shows that a valid ticket is available. No changes have been made anywhere. Searched on internet and haven't found anything. How do I find out where the problem is?

These packages are installed:

> pip (1.5.4) 
>   pycrypto (2.6.1)
>   pykerberos (1.1.13) python-apt
>   (0.9.3.5ubuntu2) python-debian (0.1.21-nmu2ubuntu2) python-ntlm3
>   (1.0.2) pywinrm (0.2.0)

Comment: After a lot of digging around, I found that there was another cache file in the /tmp folder. I must have done something because of which that file got created. Deleted that file and the problem resolved.

Turns out, today again I have the same problem and this time I do not have another cache file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I was using the pywinrm library on a linux machine. The solution was to have the domain as upper casing. Example: user@DOMAIN.COM.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My problem with the same message was related to a wrong reverse pointer in DNS. I got the idea from [Pat Suwalski](https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2014-January/177989.html). I guess a missing DNS pointer could have a similar effect. I just wanted to post this here since the error message is similar.

> kerberos: authGSSClientStep() failed: ((''Unspecified GSS failure. 
>   Minor code may provide more information'', 851968), (''Server not
>   found in Kerberos database'', -1765328377))

The Ansible documentation related to Windows changed for the better in recent years:

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_setup.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/windows_winrm.html